# Can I include jQuery and AJAX in the same file? Would this conflict?

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento, prototypejs, conflict

Can I include jQuery and AJAX in the same file?  Would this conflict?

I am attempting to include jQuery with a Magento GO template, but when I upload and include jQuery in the template, the drop down menus/etc. stop working.  The links all still work fine, but the dropdown menus, and other similar functionality stop working...

I believe this may be because Magento includes AJAX in the hosted solution on their end..?

Comment: Did you put jQuery to be first in the file?

Comment: JQuery does not conflict with ajax. It may conflict with other js libraries. As Cipi said try including jquery before anything else(if not doing already).

Answer (score 5):

The first line of your jQuery code needs to be:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

The [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) function takes out a lot of what causes cross-library errors.

Answer (score 3):

No, using jQuery along with another library that uses AJAX does not cause any conflicts.

What can cause a conflict is that the jQuery library uses the `$` identifier. If the other code is also using that, they won't work togehter unless you use the [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) method in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Magento includes Prototype by default.  It's strongly recommended that you do NOT add jQuery unless it cannot be avoided. Pretty much any functionality that jQuery provides is also available in [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/)/[Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/), it's just not as popular (and/or well marketed) as jQuery.

As the other answers have suggested, you need to put jQuery into `noConflict` mode. You will find that you might still encounter other issues, but it's a start.